# Asynchronous Java: How to organize nested subscribes that must be done sequentially?

Tags: java, asynchronous, reactive-programming, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I have a workflow which resembles this:

```
flux1.subscribe(result1 -> {
    flux2ThatDependsOnResult1.subscribe(result2 -> {
        flux3TheDependsOnResult2.subscribe(result3 -> {
        ...
        })
    })
})
```

(Using Spring Webflux)

All the nesting makes this code hard to work with. Is there a better way to write these?

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at `concatMap` or `flatMap` operators instead of subscribing on each "step"